# Use only parameters with specific value in if statement

Tags: c#

This is a little bit of a weird question, but this has me stumped for some reason. I have the below Extension function which receives 4 string parameters which will contain one of 3 values ("Match", "No Match", "Empty"). Within the function I have an if statement in which I need the condition to contain only the parameters that contain value "Match".

```
public static void AddIfNotNullAndInAdvancedSearch(
    this List<TreeDocument> docs, 
    TreeDocument value, 
    string studytitlecontainsshearch, 
    string outputtitlecontainssearch, 
    string datasetnamecontainssearch, 
    string templatenamecontainssearch)
{
    if (value.Path != null && 
        (studytitlecontainsshearch == "Match" && 
         outputtitlecontainssearch == "Match" && 
         datasetnamecontainssearch == "Match" && 
         templatenamecontainssearch == "Match")) 
    { 
        docs.Add(value); 
    }
}
```

With my code above, if for example studytitlecontainsshearch is "Empty", then the if statement resolves to false. However, in this scenario I only want to have the remaining 3 parameters in the statement and not ones that contain "Empty" or "No Match". So if only two parameters contain "Match", I want to have only those in the if statement.

I am probably missing a really obvious solution to this so apologies in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "I only want to have those in the if statement"? It sounds like you probably want to create a count of how many parameters are "Match" and how many are "Empty", and use those results. (Have you considered using an enum for that instead of a string? It sounds like there are only a few options. I'd also strongly recommend that you follow .NET naming conventions, and use line breaks more liberally, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Try to change your approach. Don't start thinking about each value combination for each parameter, think about when do you need to add value to Doc.

Comment: @Jon, I mean that I do not want to include the parameters that contain anything other than "Match" in my if statement

Comment: You are saying that you want to ignore parameters that do not match the condition. What this means is that if **any** of the parameters match the condition, you want to add the value. My answer below does exactly this.

Comment: @nerdalert What do you need on this condition so that you can `Add(value)` ?

Comment: Leonardo I believe you posted an answer a little while back which is deleted. This lead me to the right track.

Answer (score 3):

So do you mean you want to get a true if **any** of the parameters is "Match"? Then you need to change your `&&` (means '**And** also') to `||` (means '**Or** else')

```
if (value.Path != null && 
    (studytitlecontainsshearch == "Match" || 
     outputtitlecontainssearch == "Match" || 
     datasetnamecontainssearch == "Match" || 
     templatenamecontainssearch == "Match")) 
{ 
    docs.Add(value); 
}
```

Edit: As it seems you want to not add the doc if any param is "No Match", you can change it to:
Another edit: In fact you also still need to check that there is a match

```
if (value.Path != null && 
    (studytitlecontainsshearch == "Match" || 
     outputtitlecontainssearch == "Match" || 
     datasetnamecontainssearch == "Match" || 
     templatenamecontainssearch == "Match") &&
    (studytitlecontainsshearch != "No Match" && 
     outputtitlecontainssearch != "No Match" && 
     datasetnamecontainssearch != "No Match" && 
     templatenamecontainssearch != "No Match")) 
{ 
    docs.Add(value); 
}
```

You could actually simplify the method using 'params' instead of specifying each parameter. This will allow you to add more search terms without changing the method signature later:

```
public static void AddIfNotNullAndInAdvancedSearch(
    this List<TreeDocument> docs, 
    TreeDocument value, 
    params string[] searches)
{
    if (value.Path != null && 
        searches.Any(x => x == "Match") &&
        !searches.Any(x => x == "No Match")) 
    { 
        docs.Add(value); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work for my needs because if I use the OR operator then it will add to docs different docs that contain either of the matching searches.

Comment: Perhaps I should give a little more background as to when this extension is called because this may seem confusing

Comment: It definitely does

Comment: @nerdalert: Yes, your question is *very* confusing at the moment. At least for me.

Comment: @nerdalert I have updated this and expect that the lower solution is actually what you want, rather than your posted answer. See my comment on there for why.

Comment: Steve this seems to be working exactly how I wanted, I'll do further testing but it seems perfect so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to make this work is to make a different class:

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public string SearchType { get; set; }
    public string SearchResult { get; set; }
}
```

Then use this class for params in the `AddIfNotNullAndInAdvancedSearch` method like this:

```
public static void AddIfNotNullAndInAdvancedSearch(
        this List<TreeDocument> docs,
        TreeDocument value,
        params SearchModel[] searchCriteria)
    {
        var filteredSearchCriteria = searchCriteria
            .Where(x => x.SearchResult != "No Match" &&
                        x.SearchResult != "Empty")
            .ToList();

        if (filteredSearchCriteria.Any() && 
            filteredSearchCriteria.All(x => x.SearchResult == "Match"))
        {
            docs.Add(value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't know if I understood your doubt, but I will try help you.

I see many solutions for this case, for example you can change the `&&` to 
`||` in your if statement to compare your strings

But if you want something a little more expressive and flexible you can do something like that.

```
public static void AddIfNotNullAndInAdvancedSearch(this List<TreeDocument> docs, TreeDocument value, List<string> filters)
{
     if(value.Path != null && filters.Exists(x => x == "Match")) docs.Add(value);
}
```